# Trying to perform an SQL join between two filtered tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join, where-clause

I am trying to join two tables, but with filters applied to both. eg. Have the left table filtered and then joined with a filtered version of the right table, preserving the left table.

My query is below:

```
SELECT REP_Exposure_secured.DeliveryRegion, REP_Exposure_secured.DeliveryCountry, 
REP_Exposure_secured.EngagementCompanyCode, REP_Exposure_secured.EngagementId, 
REP_Exposure_secured.Engagement, REP_Exposure_secured.EngagementType,
REP_Exposure_secured.EngagementStatus, REP_Exposure_secured.EngagementPartner, 
REP_Exposure_secured.EngagementPartnerID, REP_Exposure_secured.EngagementManager, 
REP_Exposure_secured.ServiceLine, REP_Exposure_secured.SubServiceLine, 
REP_Exposure_secured.Competency, REP_Exposure_secured.ServiceOffering, 
REP_Exposure_secured.EngagementServiceCode, REP_Exposure_secured.EngagementService,
REP_Exposure_secured.EngagementLastTimeChargedDate, REP_Exposure_secured.EngagementCreationDate, 
REP_Exposure_secured.Account, REP_Exposure_secured.UltimateDunsNumber, 
REP_Exposure_secured.Client, REP_Exposure_secured.ClientID,
REP_Exposure_secured.AR_0_30, REP_Exposure_secured.AR_31_60, 
REP_Exposure_secured.AR_61_90, REP_Exposure_secured.AR_91_120, 
REP_Exposure_secured.AR_121_150, REP_Exposure_secured.AR_151_179, 
REP_Exposure_secured.AR_180_365, REP_Exposure_secured.AR_Above_365,
REP_Exposure_secured.MTD_TER, REP_Exposure_secured.MTD_BilledAmt, 
REP_Exposure_secured.MTD_CollectedAmt, REP_Exposure_secured.UnbilledInvAging30Amt, 
REP_Exposure_secured.UnbilledInvAging60Amt, REP_Exposure_secured.UnbilledInvAging90Amt,
REP_Exposure_secured.UnbilledInvAging150Amt, REP_Exposure_secured.UnbilledInvAging180Amt, 
REP_Exposure_secured.UnbilledInvAging365Amt, REP_Exposure_secured.UnbilledInvAging365PlusAmt, 
REP_FTEReport_secured.GPN, REP_FTEReport_secured.Country AS FTE_Country,
REP_FTEReport_secured.Country AS FTE_Country.EmployeeName AS FTE_Name

FROM Reporting.REP_Exposure_secured

LEFT JOIN REP_FTEReport_secured 
ON REP_Exposure_secured.EngagementPartnerID = REP_FTEReport_secured.GUI

WHERE (REP_Exposure_secured.DeliveryCountry IN ('Cambodia', 'Singapore', 'Malaysia', 'Indonesia',
'Guam', 'Laos', 'Maldives', 'Myanmar', 'Philippines', 'Sri Lanka', 'Thailand', 'Vietnam')
OR REP_Exposure_secured.DeliveryCountry LIKE 'Brunei Daruss%')
AND REP_Exposure_secured.SubServiceLine='Forensics'
AND REP_Exposure_secured.EngagementType LIKE 'External%'
AND REP_Exposure_secured.Currency='USD'
AND REP_FTEReport_secured.AccountingCycleDate IN
    (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT
            MAX(AccountingCycleDate)
        FROM
            REP_FTEReport_secured
            )
AND REP_FTEReport_secured.Country IN ('Brunei', 'Cambodia', 'Guam', 'Indonesia', 'Lao', 'Malaysia', 'Maldives',
'Myanmar', 'Philippines', 'Singapore', 'Sri Lanka', 'Thailand', 'Vietnam')
AND REP_FTEReport_secured.SubServiceLine='Forensics'
AND REP_FTEReport_secured.RankName IN ('Partner', 'Director', 'Executive Director');
```

This returns the following error:

> : ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '.'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'. (156)")

Any help on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not related to your problem, but please start using aliases in your queries, it can make them so much better readable

Comment: And some indentation would also improve the readability

Comment: Thanks a lot @GuidoG - I'll take this on. Didn't even know about aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is with this line, the last field in your select clause.

```
REP_FTEReport_secured.Country AS FTE_Country.EmployeeName AS FTE_Name
```

it has 2 aliases and 2 `dots`

The mixup is in the last 2 lines

```
REP_FTEReport_secured.GPN, REP_FTEReport_secured.Country AS FTE_Country,
REP_FTEReport_secured.Country AS FTE_Country.EmployeeName AS FTE_Name
```

Lets make them more readable first

```
REP_FTEReport_secured.GPN, 
REP_FTEReport_secured.Country AS FTE_Country,
REP_FTEReport_secured.Country AS FTE_Country.EmployeeName AS FTE_Name
```

now you can see you have a problem at the end.
You probably need this

```
REP_FTEReport_secured.GPN, 
REP_FTEReport_secured.Country AS FTE_Country,
REP_FTEReport_secured.EmployeeName AS FTE_Name
```

As you can see, just by making the query more readable, in this case only putting one field per line, in stead of 2, the error became visible immediate

Comment: Thanks so much @GuidoG - copy and paste error and couldn't see wood for the trees.

Comment: @Omar that is one reason you should start using aliases, it makes the code so much more readable and errors like this would stand out much better